# No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for the language 'nil'

Tags: babel

I simply load the package `babel` with the options `nil` and `french`. I need the language `nil` to be able to prevent hyphenations of certain words like names of persons or publishers.

In the past, I used the file `zerohyph.tex` that I declared in the `language.dat` file but babel works in a totally different way, now.

In the documentation, they say to use the language `nil` which corresponds to no hyphenation at all. Then why do I have a warning telling me there is no pattern for that language and pdfLaTeX will use the patterns preloaded for english instead?

That package is a nightmare. I can't even find the place that warning is written : it is not in the `label.sty` file.

Comment: The `babel` documentation doesn't say that, and in fact I don't think it's a good idea. Use `hyphenrules` instead. Except if you are using `luatex`, `babel` has not changed the behavior of `language.dat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In texlive 2015 there is no problem. In the miktex the "language" is missing. A bug report has been made. It also contains a description how to add the "nohyphenation" language to miktex.

https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1968/

Run on a command line

```
 initexmf --edit-config-file languages
```

This will open the local languages.ini.
Then add an entry for nohyphenation.

```
[nohyphenation]
loader=zerohyph.tex
lefthyphenmin=2
righthyphenmin=3
attributes=
```

Save the file. Then go to miktex settings. nohyphenation should now
be in the language list. Uncheck and recheck it so that language.dat
and the formats are updated.

You can find the warning you mentioned in `switch.def`

## Addition

with babel 3.9n and lualatex it seems to be necessary to add also a language "nil".

Comment: I indeed use the MikTeX distribution. Thank you very much for your answer. It is very complete.